# How can a differential equation be found given its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example, if given a solution of $$y = c~\sin(4x+5)$$

How can I find a second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients that has this solution?

How can I find any other solution (such as the cosine solution).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: Have you tried integrating twice?

Answer (score 0):

(a) If you differentiate this twice, then you have the equation you want. Namely, $y''=-16y.$

(b) To find other solutions, for example a cosine (which is just a shifted sine anyway), substitute $y=\cos(ax+b)$ into the equation to determine constants $a,b$ satisfying the condition. Any constant multiple of this will also be a solution.